# Errors while connecting to Azure Container

Tags: node.js, azure, express, file, azure-blob-storage

i am trying to connect to the azure container and to save a text file

```
  const azure = require('azure-storage');
    const BlobServiceClient = azure.createBlobService();
    
    const AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = "my key";
    
    const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
    
    
    const containerName = "tempp";
    
    console.log('\nCreating container...');
    console.log('\t', containerName);
    
    // Get a reference to a container
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

const blobName = 'test' + uuidv1() + '.txt';

// Get a block blob client
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

console.log('\nUploading to Azure storage as blob:\n\t', blobName);



const data = "message";
const uploadBlobResponse =   blockBlobClient.upload(data, data.length);


console.log("Blob was uploaded successfully. requestId: ", uploadBlobResponse.requestId);
```

The azure_storage connection string I got it from /security + networking/Access Keys  by following the documentation but when running the project i am getting an error

```
Error: Credentials must be provided when creating a service client.
```

Comment: I think you're mixing old SDK code (`azure-storage`) with new SDK code (`@azure/storage-blob`).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri) , I tried to repro in my local and able to deploy files to my container in azure.

Make sure you have install the following `nuget packages`

**Azure.Storage.Blobs(12.10.0)** latest sdk,     **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration** & **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json**

[image]

Here is the Open [source code](https://github.com/techwithpat/Upload-files-to-Microsoft-Azure-Blob-Storage-with-CSharp/tree/main/AzureBlobStorage) that i followed to upload files to my Container.

[image]

For more information please refer this [MS DOC for.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) & [MS DOC for Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs).

Comment: The OP was asking about node.js while your code is using .NET.

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy Meng .I have update with provided link for Node.js .